# Discover website's feed URL

Tags: rss, feed, atom-feed

How can I discover a website's feed URL?

When I grab [Microsoft's blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/microsoft_blog/) HTML, I can see this:

```html
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Site Home (RSS 2.0)" href="http://blogs.technet.com/rss.aspx"  />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="B1ackD0g&#39;s Comments (RSS 2.0)" href="/members/B1ackD0g/comments/rss.aspx"  />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="B1ackD0g&#39;s Activities (RSS 2.0)" href="/members/B1ackD0g/activities/rss.aspx"  />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Activities of People B1ackD0g Follows (RSS 2.0)" href="/members/B1ackD0g/activities/followersrss.aspx"  />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="B1ackD0g&#39;s Groups Activities (RSS 2.0)" href="/members/B1ackD0g/activities/groupsrss.aspx"  />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="The Official Microsoft Blog – News and Perspectives from Microsoft (RSS 2.0)" href="http://blogs.technet.com/b/microsoft_blog/rss.aspx"  />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="The Official Microsoft Blog – News and Perspectives from Microsoft (Atom 1.0)" href="http://blogs.technet.com/b/microsoft_blog/atom.aspx"  />
```

What I can assume here is that I can look for  tags with hrefs that starts with "http://blogs.technet.com/b/microsoft_blog/"

Is this safe to assume?

What I need to do is basically get a URL and return its feed URL.

Comment: What language do you use? Javascript, PHP, ASP?

Answer (score 0):

There is no safe way to assume what a website's feed url is without knowing it. In this example the attribute `type` value seems to be enough to determine the feed but that is not guaranteed to be set outside of your example. You can try and guess by searching the markup for links containing RSS or even testing against a service like feedburner http://feeds.feedburner.com/somedomain but you still can not be sure.